# How can I prevent aptitude from upgrading me past lenny? (Debian Linux)

Tags: debian, aptitude

I can't seem to stop aptitude from upgrading all my packages to testing or beyond.

I'm running Debian lenny, and generally I want to stick with packages from lenny unless I explicitly say otherwise.  For particular features I may upgrade a particular package to a version from testing or experimental, but in general I want to stick to the lenny versions.  In my `/etc/apt/apt.conf` I have uttered

```
APT::Default-Release "lenny";
```

and my `/etc/apt/preferences` is listed below.

**Problem**: whenever I hit the U key in aptitude, it wants to upgrade *all* my packages at least to testing.

**Question**: how can I arrange that the U key in aptitude installs only new versions in lenny, not newer versions from testing or elsewhere?

My `/etc/apt/preferences` (where I freely admit I don't know what I'm doing) is

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 90

Package: *
Pin: release a=experimental
Pin-Priority: 89

Package: *
Pin: release a=gutsy
Pin-Priority: 88

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50
```

Comment: What's your /etc/apt/sources.list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `APT::Default-Release` to "stable", not "lenny".  The Release file talks in terms of release stages, not release codenames.

Comment: As of Debian 6.0 (Squeeze), you can use codenames with the `APT::Default-Release` setting.

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/apt/sources.list. Try using release codenames.

i.e.
deb http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free